# UserControl in windows phone 8.1 blank template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My requirement is masterpage in windows phone 8.1 blank template, i searched  in the google, they suggest the usercontrol, i applied that scenario but not working,Below is my tried sample code. 
`I'm try create Application where i required to use User Control.I'm already created MainPage.xaml here code below

```
`

<Page
    x:Class="VtDesigning.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VtDesigning"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"  
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and usercontrol defined below

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="VtDesigning.MyUserControl2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VtDesigning"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Height="50" Background="Chocolate">
            <TextBlock Text="hi hellow how are you"
                       FontSize="25" 
                       Margin="0,0,154,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How to i call this usercontrol in MainPage.xaml.

Thanks,
Venky.

Answer (score 1):

Set a reference to the location of the user control and add the user control to your layout as a normal control

```
<Page
x:Class="VtDesigning.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:VtDesigning"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:project="using:MyProject.UserControls"
mc:Ignorable="d"  
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <project:MyUserControl/>
</Grid>
```